# Use value variable with double quotes as command parameter, but without having single quotes

Tags: bash, variable

I need to run something like `mycommand -f "a","b"`

But I need to run it inside this kind of bash script:

```bsh
p="\"a\",\"b\""

mycommand -f "$p"
```

But if I run this script the command that start is

```
mycommand -f '"a","b"'
```

and not

```
mycommand -f "a","b"
```

How to have `$p` as parameter without the single quote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would run `mycommand -f "a","b"` on the command line, that would be the same as running `mycommand -f "a,b"`, or `mycommand -f a,b`. The shell removes the quotes, and what `mycommand` gets as arguments, are the two strings `-f` and `a,b`, with no quotes in them.

Now, if you want to have the latter inside a variable, just store it in a variable without any extra quotes, and use it with `"$var"`. You can of course use quotes when assigning the value, those will just be removed the same way as they would be if the quoted string was given directly as an argument to the command.

```
var="a","b"         # or
var="a,b"           # or
var=a,b             
mycommand -f "$var"
```

Though of course if the value is actually e.g. `foo bar, this that` with whitespace, or contains other characters special to the shell, then you need at least some quotes:

```
var="foo bar, this that"
mycommand -f "$var"
```

---

If you have:

```
p="\"a\",\"b\""
mycommand -f "$p"
```

then, after the quotes and escapes are processed, the variable `p` would contain `"a","b"`, and the argument to `mycommand` would also be that exact string. That's a different string from the previous.

With `set -x`, Bash, ksh and zsh would show that as `mycommand -f '"a","b"'`, since they display the arguments in a format that's *valid as input to the shell*, and a string containing double quotes will need some quoting. Backslashes would work, but those shells
prefer single quotes for display there.

(On the other hand e.g. Dash would not do that, its `set -x` prints ambiguous output that does not survive the round-trip intact.)

Comment: Perhaps see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2):

I feel very very stupid.

My command run in this way `mycommand -f "a","b"`. If I run it without double quotes - `mycommand -f a,b` - it does not work.

For this reason, I have added the escaped double quotes in the variable: `p="\"a a\",\"b\""`.

I have to be more precise, I have some white space and the real command is `mycommand -f "a a","b"`.

I found out and that I must study: it's not necessary to add the quotes as variable value, bash does everything right and magically for me.

I set `p="a a,b"`, and then I can run simply `mycommand -f "$p"`

Comment: what the shell does here is what any programming language does: it just uses the value of the variable, it doesn't parse its contents for shell syntax. Something like `char *s = "foo()"; printf("%s\n", s);` in C just prints `foo()`, it doesn't call the function `foo` like `printf("%s\n", foo());` would. Of course, the way next to everything in the shell is a string, quotes or not, and the fact that unquoted variable expansions go through word processing muddy the waters a bit, but in general, the shell is not a macro processor, but a programming language (even if a quite quirky one).